# Which phones today uses Android Common Kernel?

Tags: kernel, builds

[Android Common Kernel](https://source.android.com/devices/architecture/kernel/android-common) is an effor by google to unificate the kernels of the phones.

What are examples of phones today that uses Android Common Kernels, except Pixel?

Comment: What issue are you trying to solve? [List questions are no good fit for Q&A sites](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/98366/192154), and hence are [considered off-topic](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/139618/192154).

Comment: usually one care for own single device only - except for developers. list devices you're targeting, so we can answer Android Common Kernel for devices of interest only

Comment: @alecxs I live in a country where there's only Xiaomi, Motorola and Samsung, mainly. I wanted one of these, to play with.